# How to locally store user information when he is using facebook messenger chatbot?

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-messenger, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I followed facebook's documentation and set up my messenger bot. It works fine when it's just me who's using it, but I don't know how to create variables and store information in them locally so that I can have individual information about each user.

For eg. If I ask them to type their phone number, how/where should I save it, so that it isn't overwritten if a new user comes and inputs his number (which happens, if the variable is declared globally), and I can also use it later.

I used Node JS and followed the steps they mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: You get the messenger user id from Facebook. That is unique for each user

Comment: So I should globally create a key value pair for all IDs with the phone numbers? Is there any other way that you can think of?

Comment: No key it on user ID

Comment: Alright, thanks.
Also, if something else comes to your mind, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You have node js server as a backend which can communicate to a (mysql/sqlite) database.

Fb provides `senderId` with each request and also there is another graph API for getting user's other information like Name, Age, Gender, profile pic link etc

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/SENDER_ID?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN

You can have a table in your (mysql/sqlite) database where you can store `senderId` as a unique key and other information including phone number (which you are getting by asking user) in other columns.

[Here's](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-public_profile) the documentation link for public profile API.